# Dynamically populate select tag on change

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I'm looking for a way to affect another select tag by selecting a value in another select tag. When I do this, I get this error:

> GET http://localhost/laravel/public/select?vestiging=Lichtenvoorde 500
>   (Internal Server Error).

Thank you

---

**home.blade.php**:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var select_vestiging = $('#sel1');
        select_vestiging.change(function() {
            var vestiging = $('#sel1').val();
            $.get( "select?vestiging="+vestiging, function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Gegevens invullen</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option selected >Selecteer een vestiging</option>
                        @foreach ($vestigingen as $vestiging)
                            <option value='{{ $vestiging -> Plaats }}'>{{ $vestiging -> Plaats }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </br>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel2">
                      <option selected >Selecteer een center</option>
                        @if (!empty($centers))
                                @foreach ($centers as $center)
                                    <option value='{{ $center }}'>{{ $centers }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </select>
                    </br>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel3">
                    </select>
                    </br>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel4">
                    </select>
                    </br>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel5">
                    </select>
                    </br>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel6">
                    </select>
                    </br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**homeController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use DB;
use View;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $vestigingen = DB::table('vestigingen')->distinct()->get();

        return View::make('home', compact('vestigingen'));
    }

    public function select(Request $request)
    {
        //$centers = $request->input('vestiging');

        $centers = [
            "1","2","3","4","5"
        ];

        return View::make('home', compact('centers'));

    }
}
```

**route.php**:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/select', 'HomeController@select');
});
```

Comment: The error means you have an issue in your PHP code which you need to debug. If you check the request in the network console you should see a more detailed error message

Comment: Thank you, now the error is: "the variable vestigingen is not defined". I think the make::view overwrites the other variable.